# Running Snowflake query in Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a scenario where I will have to do some ETL-like operations in Python where the database is Snowflake. I am new to Python and after installing the pip for the Python and Snowflake connector, I am trying to run a simple code for doing a select * from a table. I added bits and pieces of code from various sources with a view to understand how the process works. I am getting the below error and unfortunately am not able to find anything conclusive online.

Error:

OperationalError: 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://nq13914.southeast-asia.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=7325eb5e-eec6-4ec9-976a-6dbd00852fc3&databaseName=util_db&schemaName=public&warehouse=compute_wh&request_guid=4674d312-5cfd-4944-a8db-7dda073b7b44

Code:

```
import snowflake.connector as sf
import pandas


ctx = sf.connect (
    user = 'floatinginthecloud89',
    password = '',
    account = 'nq13914.southeast-asia',
    warehouse = 'compute_wh',
    database = 'util_db',
    schema = 'public'
)
print("Got the context object")

cs = ctx.cursor()
print("Got the cursor object")


try:
    cs.execute("select * from util_db.public.qwerty1;")
    df = cs.fetch_pandas_all()
    df.info()
    print("__________")
    print(df.to_string())
finally:
    cs.close()     
ctx.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me with my own Snowflake account. Seems like your snowflake account (or the account that your company is using) is either wrong or has some [Network Policy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html) applied to it.

Using your browser, you should be able to go to https://nq13914.southeast-asia.snowflakecomputing.com/console/login#/ and see a login screen. In your case you cannot (nor can I) so the `nq13914.southeast-asia` is either wrong or being blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Simon. I added azure at the end of Asia. So the account name now looks like this --> account = 'nq13914.southeast-asia.azure',

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the error now --> Object 'UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.QWERTY1' does not exist or not authorized.

Comment: That's just a permissions issue. Make sure the table is accessible to the role you're using to log into Snowflake through python. `show grants on table UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.QWERTY1`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do run the script. Of the issues faced, the packages installed caused issues due to the version. So uninstalled and installed again. Had to do that a few times before it worked.